# How to convert variable length string to vector?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, word2vec

I am working on classification algorithm and I get different string codes which have some pattern.

```
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| Column 1   | Column 2    | Column 3     |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| MN009      | JIK9PO      | LEFTu        |
| MN010      | JIK9POS     | LEFTu        |
| MN011      | JIK9POKI    | LEFTu        |
| MN012      | KIJU        | LEFTu        |
| MN013      | RANDOM      | LEFTu        |
| MN014      | FT          | LEFTu        |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
```

For column 1 and 3 the feature set can be a vector length 5.

But I do not know how to create feature set which can accommodate column 2 as well.

**Considerations:**

1. Create a feature vector of size equal to size of longest string
   value and for smaller strings add some filler.
2. Truncate strings to a fixed length like 5 here and ignore extra
   characters.

Hope I am clear with the question. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean "accommodate"? Are these... features? What is wrong with them?

Comment: I just want to create features out of string values. Accommodate has no special mean, sorry for confusion.

Comment: Not really a programming question, maybe better for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Amit Did you find a solution to your problem? I am working on something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. The one you mentioned; predefine a length, zero-padding sequences
   that fall short of it. This length can either be set to:

   - the longest currently present sample (larger feature space ⇒ time / memory complexity consequences),
   - or to a shorter length (information loss ⇒ predictive power penalty). Information loss stems from either ignoring sequences
     above that length or truncating them and using their cut-down
     versions.

     In both cases you should probably quantify the impact of your choice
     (i.e. how much information have I discarded from my data by discarding/truncating, or how much larger is my problem space compared to if I used a smaller length).
2. Dynamic graphs, essentially variable shape networks, can handle sequences of different sizes. Such capacities are offered by [PyTorch](http://pytorch.org/about/) and are (relatively) straightforward to implement ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244053/pytorch-relation-between-dynamic-computational-graphs-padding-dataloader) SO question)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the docs, [pack-padded-sequence](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.0/nn.html?highlight=packed%20sequence#pack-padded-sequence)
helps you avoid dynamic graphs and allows the network to disregard padded input. This would be straight forward to implement.

> Packs a Variable containing padded sequences of variable length.